# FabricJS big grid is losing its shape in zoom out

Tags: javascript, canvas, grid, zooming, fabricjs

I made zoom function with big grid and fixed the performance issues.

However, when I zoom out the grid looks broken as below.

Before zoom out:

[image]

And After:

[image]

**EDIT:**
Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mudin/Lm0yj6xa/)

```
let MAX_WIDTH = 10000;
let GRID_IMAGE = 'grid image link';
let canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
var rect = new fabric.Rect({
  width: MAX_WIDTH,
  height: MAX_WIDTH,
  originX: 'center',
  originY: 'center',
  selectable: false,
  evented: false,
  objectCaching: false,
  dirty: true
});
canvas.add(rect);
```

Comment: Did you try anything? And could you please point out what was the performance issues before you solved them ?

Comment: @Humoyun Oh I forgot to share my jsfiddle

Comment: I used image instead of drawing lines, and set `objectCaching:false` to make it not blurry

Comment: any solution to this?